# How do you set a requirement or rule over a set of rows where there is already data on excel?

Tags: excel, function, hyperion, essbase

I have an excel sheet that has data extracted from Hyperion Essbase. I'd like to put a sort of rounding rule on that data without removing the numbers generated from Essbase. For example, in a cell there's the value $13.5232, I'd like to set a rule over that cell telling it to round the absolute value of it to two decimal places if the second decimal is greater than or equal to 0.01, if so than make it 0, if not than keep that number rounded to the second decimal.

To achieve this I simply created another chart on the side with an `=IF(ROUND())` equation but I would like to get rid of that chart and apply that rule over the data already extracted by Essbase.

Answer (score 0):

The approach you're taking is probably the most common, which is where you have your typical "retrieve" area and then a separate area that references that and has the formulas you need to adjust that data. Another approach would be that you could add a new Scenario to the cube to perform rounding as needed. You can also use conditional formatting to format, as in here: [How do you add a rule to cells in excel?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51065070/how-do-you-add-a-rule-to-cells-in-excel)